# Intersection of two lines. Which of the following equations is the most resource-efficient?

Tags: python, performance, line, intersection

In my program, I need to find the y value of the intersection of two lines.

First line is denoted by: y=a1*x+b1
Second line is denoted by y=a2*x+b2

Solving for x in each, setting the equations equal to each other, solving for y and rearranging, I came up with four different but equivalent (that is yet to be determined, actually) equations:

1. y=(b1/a1-b2/a2)/(1/a1-1/a2)
2. y=(b2+(a2/a1)*b1)/(1-a2/a1)
3. y=(a1*b2-b1*a2)/(a1-a2)
4. y=a1*((b2-b1)/(a1-a2))+b1

Now, I ran the following Python code to check if all equations give equal answers:

```
import random

def linearfunction(coords1,coords2):
    x1=coords1[0]
    x2=coords2[0]
    y1=coords1[1]
    y2=coords2[1]
    a=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    b=y2-a*x2
    return [a,b]

def doesitequal():
    first=[random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)]
    second=[random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)]
    third=[random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)]
    fourth=[random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)]

    a1=linearfunction(first,second)[0]
    b1=a1=linearfunction(first,second)[1]
    a2=linearfunction(third,fourth)[0]
    b2=linearfunction(third,fourth)[1]

    firstversion=(b1/a1-b2/a2)/(1/a1-1/a2)
    secondversion=(b2+(a2/a1)*b1)/(1-a2/a1)
    thirdversion=(a1*b2-b1*a2)/(a1-a2)
    fourthversion=a1*((b2-b1)/(a1-a2))+b1

    print('First equation: ', firstversion)
    print('Second equation:', secondversion)
    print('Third equation:', thirdversion)
    print('Fourth equation', fourthversion)

for i in range(100):
    doesitequal()
```

Surprisingly (to me), the second equation always returns a value that is slightly off the other ones, which return values that are exactly equal to each other. Please try it for yourselves to see what I mean.

Example output:

```
First equation:  -71.13238078843175
Second equation: -67.71148218281976
Third equation: -71.13238078843175
Fourth equation -71.1323807884317
First equation:  190.62597809076678
Second equation: 186.9640062597809
Third equation: 190.6259780907668
Fourth equation 190.62597809076686
First equation:  81.93742601048538
Second equation: 80.48246237104686
Third equation: 81.93742601048537
Fourth equation 81.93742601048537
```

So my first question is:

Why dos the second equation return slightly different values than what it should? Did I mess up my arithmetics? Or is it due to the way Python evaluates given math operations?

My second question is:

Out of these four formulas, which is the most memory-efficient one? That is, which one is the least likely to cause lags in calculations if the line intersection is to be calculated a huge amount of times in a short time period?

A wild guess would be that the efficiency is inversely proportional to the number of operations in a given equation. For instance, first equation involves 7 math operations, whereas last one involves 5, meaning the last one is more efficient than the first one. However, different math operations are likely not to be equivalent to each other in terms of complexity and, hence, efficiency. That is why I am unsure about the answer to this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried profiling any or all of them? What do you mean *"slightly different values"*?

Comment: I edited the question and added example output for you to see the differences in returned values.

Comment: You have `b1=a1=...` is that deliberate? The 2nd formula is definitely not correct

Comment: That was a typo indeed. I corrected the 2nd formula, thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer to show your error in 2nd equation but I'd like to comment that this kind of stuff (object intersections) is sometimes developed using homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
2. y=(b2+(a2/a1)*b1)/(1-a2/a1)
```

is

```
     a2 b1
b2 + -----
      a1
----------
      a2
  1 - --
      a1
```

is

```
(a2 b1 + a1 b2) / a1
--------------------
   (a1 - a2) / a1
```

is

```
a2 b1 + a1 b2
-------------
   a1 - a2
```

that it is to be compared with eq.3 (the one I'd use)

```
a2 b1 - a1 b2
-------------
   a2 - a1
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, could you explain why you would choose eq 3?

Comment: simple, symmetric, memorable

Comment: @user3000014 write the simplest code that works, optimize only code that works and needs optimization (in many cases you can say "code that works and _hardly_ needs optimization")